# "Failed to create DataStorage" error when using Pig with Hadoop

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig, data-storage

I've been trying to get Pig 0.9.0 to run using Apache Hadoop 0.20.203.0. I've looked high and low over google and mailing lists and even this question: [cant run pig with single node hadoop server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6766931/cant-run-pig-with-single-node-hadoop-server) , but I still can't get Grunt, the Pig shell, to run in a cluster-setup (I can run the prompt fine in local mode, of course).

I've tried the solutions given - recompiling without hadoop, adding the hadoop library and the pig-withouthadoop.jar to my PIG_CLASSPATH variable...nothing works. I just get the error

> 2011-08-02 10:56:00,709 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.Main - ERROR 2999: Unexpected internal error. Failed to create DataStorage

Not entirely sure where to go from here. I've seen a few discussions of this on the Apache Pig development website or something (their version control site or whatever) and there were some proposed scripts but I couldn't figure out what his wrapper script was doing or how to use it: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PIG-2183 . Maybe the solution lies in that link?

I'm running a single-node hadoop setup (NOT local mode)...Hadoop works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Check https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/PIG/FAQ#FAQ-Q%3AWhatshallIdoifIsaw%22FailedtocreateDataStorage%22%3F

Comment: Thanks for the link, but following that didn't seem to remedy that. This has since become not too big of a pressing issue, so I think I will just wait for pig 9.1 to come out, or keep looking for answers later.

Comment: The link did not help me either.

Answer (score 0):

Typically it's a library issue. Check that you have all the dependencies added to the pig file. Hard to point to the right one at the moment.